# persisting flink data to mongo

Tags: mongodb, apache-flink

I am having a flink datastream on which I am doing some processing using KeyedProcessFunction, then I need to save the data in MongoDB after processing but I am not able to so.
Can anyone provide me some input on how can I save data to Mongo from flink datastream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB isn't supported as a sink for Flink, nor has anyone in the community contributed a package for it in https://flink-packages.org/.

This means you might have to write your own sink, unless you can find something suitable somewhere.

If you need to support transactions, implementing a sink that handles this has gotten a bit easier with Flink 1.12. This is described in [FLIP-143: Unified Sink API](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/FLIP-143%3A+Unified+Sink+API).

Comment: actually i was planning the same i.e to write own sink but couldn't find any suitable way depicting how can I achieve that for MongoDB. Everywhere what I am seeing is custom sink for rdbms

Comment: If you are looking for examples, there are the sinks in Flink itself, as well as those in Apache Bahir. However, there are very few two-phase commit sinks, and only one (so far) using FLIP-143 (the FileSink in Flink 1.12).

Comment: thanks for the help. I was able to write a sink and persist data.